# How to combine the elements of two lists using a user-specified function

Tags: list-manipulation

I have two lists of integers. From these lists I want to produce a list where each element is a fraction derived from a corresponding pair of elements in the original lists, the smaller integer of the pair  should be in the numerator.

For example, from `T1 = {0, 2, 8}`, `T2 = {3, 5, 6}` and I want to produce `T ={0, 2/5, 6/8}`. But I have no idea how to do it in *Mathematica*. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 6):

One way:

```
t1 = {0, 2, 8};
t2 = {3, 5, 6};
MapThread[
 If[# > #2, #2/#, #/#2] &,
 {t1, t2}
 ]
```

Answer (score 5):

A simple numeric approach that is naturally vectorized due to use of [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html) functions:

```
f[a_, b_] := Quiet[ (a/b)^Sign[b - a] ]
```

Test:

```
f[ {2, 3, 6, 5, 9, 7, 5}, {5, 4, 3, 4, 9, 3, 1} ]
```

> ```
> {2/5, 3/4, 1/2, 4/5, 1, 3/7, 1/5}
> ```

---

Here is a completely different approach based solely on [Attributes](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Attributes.html):

```
SetAttributes[f2, {Orderless, Listable}]

f2[a_, b_] := a/b
```

Test:

```
f2[{3, 1, 7}, {2, 4, 0}]
```

> ```
> {2/3, 1/4, 0}
> ```

Comment: Very nice, but produces an infinite expression error when 0 is in the `b`list.

Comment: @SquareOne I forgot about that case.  Thanks.

Comment: This new version is very elegant. By the way, your first version produces a correct answer (it does not fail as you said), the infinite expression message was only a warning not an error as I said (same warning also in one of @Karsten solutions).

Comment: @SquareOne  Thanks, *again*.  I guess I could just wrap that in `Quiet`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Rational @@@ Sort /@ Transpose[{T1, T2}]
(*{0, 2/5, 3/4}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Min@#/Max@# & /@ Transpose[{t1, t2}]
```

> ```
> {0, 2/5, 3/4}
> ```

```
Inner[Min@{##}/Max@{##} &, t1, t2, List]
```

> ```
> {0, 2/5, 3/4}
> ```

```
t2/t1 /. x : (# > 1 & | ComplexInfinity) -> 1/x
```

> ```
> {0, 2/5, 3/4}
> ```